# Multipage bookdown into article

Tags: r-markdown, bookdown

I'm considering to use Bookdown to write an academic paper. This includes the data processing and analysis code, plus everything else.

I know how to use Bookdown to write books where each `.Rmd` document creates its own `.html` page and a book chapter in a LaTeX PDF. I can also see how to use bookdown to write a single `.Rmd` that becomes a multi-page website and an article-style PDF. At least, that is what I think I see in [the bookdown documentation](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/a-single-document.html)

But what I am trying to figure out is how to have multiple `.Rmd` files that become a single article-style PDF. I want to have more than one `.Rmd` to keep the runtime down and my work somewhat organized, but I am not writing a book. It seems as though bookdown is built to turn document breaks into chapters, and I want them to be turned into sections. Am I missing something obvious, or is this going to require a bit of hacking to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your actual question is how to turn the top-level headers into sections instead of chapters. It depends on the `documentclass` field in `index.Rmd`. The default value of this field is `article`, which means you get sections instead of chapters. Top-level headers are converted to chapters only if the `documentclass` is for books (e.g., `documentclass: book` here: https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown-demo/blob/master/index.Rmd#L7).

Then, to render multiple `Rmd` files to a single PDF, use `bookdown::render_book()` instead of `rmarkdown::render()`.

Comment: Great! This might be best as a separate question, but is there logic as to which elements are switched in `yml` files and which are contained in the `.Rmd` directly?

Comment: The `output` field can be either in `index.Rmd` or `_output.yml`. Other fields must be in `Rmd`.